# How to get the value of another element within the same div upon click?

Tags: jquery

I've 3 div boxes & buttons with the same class names.

```
<div class="box">
    <h1 class="product_name">Product 1</h1>
    <button class="btn_buy">Buy Now</button>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <h1 class="product_name">Product 2</h1>
    <button class="btn_buy">Buy Now</button>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <h1 class="product_name">Product 3</h1>
    <button class="btn_buy">Buy Now</button>
</div>
```

**What I want to do is**, when someone clicks, eg; the 2nd button, it will display Product 2.

So, this is what I tried:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('.btn_buy').click(function(){
            var x = $('h1').html();
            alert(x);
        });
    });
```

So, this gives me the output: Product 1 , and I can understand the reason why, its because its just taking the first value of h1.

What I am stuck with is, how do I implement the `this` to this? Like how do I write the code so that only this element's parent's h1 will be selected?

So, I tried this as well:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('.btn_buy').click(function(){
            var parentTag = $(this).parent().html();
            alert(parentTag);
        });
    });
```

But, this displays all the content in it. So, how do I display just the H1 in it?

Comment: Close. `$(this).parent().find('.product_name').text()`. Though that's not particularly optimal.

Comment: @Ouroborus Thank you, I am so disappointed with myself. I actually tried parent and then I went to try find() method as well, but I didn't try it both together like how you did and it actually works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `<h1>` sibling of the clicked button so use [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```js
let x = $(this).siblings("h1").text()
```

Comment: Oh my, didn't even know there was siblings() Once  timer is up, will vote correct. Thank you!